# Improve usage of metadata-extractor with ranged GET for S3 object - What's the correct range?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, metadata-extractor

To get the Metdata object from metadata-extractor I use the following code:

```
Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(photoFileContentStream);
```

`photoFileContentStream` is an InputStream that I get from an S3 object:

```
final S3ObjectInputStream objectContent = s3.getObject(objectRequest).getObjectContent();
```

With newer versions of the AWS SDK I get the following ugly warning with the process described above:

```
WARN  com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3AbortableInputStream  - Not all bytes were read from the S3ObjectInputStream, aborting HTTP connection. This is likely an error and may result in sub-optimal behavior. Request only the bytes you need via a ranged GET or drain the input stream after use.
```

The reason seems obvious: only a small portion of the stream is used to extract the metadata from the image.

This can be improved by using a ranged get on the S3 object:

```
GetObjectRequest rangeObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key);
rangeObjectRequest.setRange(0,endRange);
final S3ObjectInputStream objectContent = s3.getObject(rangeObjectRequest).getObjectContent();
```

What I couldn't find out easily: how can I determine the correct (or a safe) value for the "endRange"? I.e. where in the stream is the metadata located?

Comment: I don't think you can reliably do this. Often the metadata is near the beginning of the file, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks, @drewnoakes, I'll continue with a regular get and use `objectContent.abort()` after the metadata has been read from the stream.

Comment: If you control the creation of the images in question, and they're all the same format, you may be able to make some guesses about the range of data needed. I would only look at this if a perf boost was needed, and of course it might not actually yield one.